# How to get epel-release / epel-release-next / powertools in CentOS Stream 9

Tags: centos, yum, dnf

I have recently installed CentOS Stream 9 and I'm finding that I can't get epel to work properly following any instructions I can find online. Resources for CentOS 8 / CentOS Stream 8 don't work and there are barely any resources for CentOS 9 Stream.

I want to install epel so I can install packages like `ddclient`, but I can't figure it out. Normally I'd just do this:

```
dnf install epel-release
dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools  # I have also tried PowerTools
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: No matching repo to modify: powertools.
```

I have messed around a lot trying to get epel so my set up may be messed up now, but here are my currently installed relevant packages and repos:

```
$ dnf list installed | grep -E 'centos|epel'
centos-gpg-keys.noarch                        9.0-3.el9                      @baseos
centos-logos.x86_64                           90.4-1.el9                     @AppStream
centos-logos-httpd.noarch                     90.4-1.el9                     @appstream
centos-stream-release.noarch                  9.0-3.el9                      @baseos
centos-stream-repos.noarch                    9.0-3.el9                      @baseos
epel-release.noarch                           8-13.el8                       @@commandline

$ dnf repolist
repo id                                                              repo name
Plex                                                                 Plex
appstream                                                            CentOS Stream 9 - AppStream
baseos                                                               CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm almost at the point of just wiping and installing CentOS Stream 8 instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`powertools` are called `crb`(CodeReady Linux Builder, or epel 9) now. To enable it, run

```bash
dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb
```

For other versions of epel, check the documentation from [Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_el9).

1. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/15/introducing-codeready-linux-builder

Comment: Thanks! Finally the correct answer for CentOS Stream 9

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible yet. I tried it too, but failed. I installed [`epel-release` and `epel-next-release`](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/next/9/Everything/x86_64/Packages/e/) from official Fedora project, but I was not able to install further packages from EPEL.

It seems there isn't any yet. I tried to search in multiple sites, but didn't find any solutions. Not even on the [CentOS mirror](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/), where the 9-stream folder is missing entirely.

For me the only solution was to downgrade to CentOS Stream 8.

Comment: Yeah in the end I was able to "upgrade" to CentOS 8 by following this guide: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-centos-7-to-centos-8/. I had to include `--nobest --allowerasing` when installing centos-loinux-release for CentOS 8.